# how to pass data to view with return response() in Laravel along with data for the ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have a grid in which all users are shown. the grid is created and shown by ajax , it has 3 buttons: add, edit, remove. I can add and delete, but since in the update.blade.php I have the user image ( which is shown by a route and controller like : `<img src="{{ route('userimage',['id' => $pass_the_id ])}}"/>`, the problem now is how do I pass variable like `$pass_the_id` that I'm about to use in the view blade?

This is the code that brings up the modal ( when edit button which is right in front of user name and id is clicked. I can get user name, family and so on and show it in the modal, but how do I pass the $id to the image route that I mentioned above?

```
    $('body').delegate('#student-info #edit','click',function (e) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.get("{{ URL::to('student/edit') }}",{id:id},function (data) {
        $('#frm-update').find('#id').val(data.id);
        $('#frm-update').find('#name').val(data.name);
        $('#frm-update').find('#family').val(data.family);
        $('#frm-update').find('#username').val(data.username);
        $('#frm-update').find('#birth_date').val(data.birth_date);
        $('#frm-update').find('#phone').val(data.cell_phone);
        $('#frm-update').find('#email').val(data.email);
        $('#frm-update').find('#gender').val(data.gender);

        $('#student-update').modal('show');
    })
})
```

here is the Laravel Controller function that is called on `URL::to('student/edit')` which I have mentioned in the above `$.get` code :

```
    public function edit(Request $request) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $contact = User::find($request->id);
        return response($contact);
    }
}
```

the responsibility of above controller function which is called during `$.get` is to get the information based on the id that I have passed. ( my grid already shows each user id in the the grid table I've created. but I don't know how to pass it to the `src="{{ route('userimage',['id' => $pass_the_id ])}}"`

here is what userimage route is doing: below is the route:

```
    Route::get('userimage/{id}','ImageController@showimage')->name('userimage');
```

and this is its code:

```
    public function showimage($id) {
    if(UserImages::selectuserimage($id) !== null) {
        $imageData = UserImages::selectuserimage($id);
        $info = $info = base64_decode($imageData);
        $img = Imgs::make($info);
        $img->encode('jpg',80);
        return $img;
    }
    else return public_path('images/Atehran.jpg');
}
```

Comment: if the is any Ambiguity for you, let me know, or provide more information

Comment: Can you explain further? with less words pls

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja hi , thanks for response . the problem is kind of simple , how do i pass the user's id to my view ( notice that the controller i used, already returns `$contact` data to the ajax success ( and with that i fill the values in the modal pop up , in that same controller i want to return the id to my view too

Comment: how to pass data to view with return response() in laravel along with data for the ajax success

Comment: let me understand please i don't get it, for example , does data.name works?

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja yes it works . all of them .

Comment: Then what do you want to achieve? you want to change the user image? or what?

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja problem is how to send the data to <img src="{{ route('userimage',['id' => $pass_the_id ])}}"/> , i can't send the id as $pass_the_id . thats my problem . i can't send the data as a variable to my view

Comment: okay i get it, you don't send $pass_the_id  to there, you need to generate a full link and append it using js
can you update your code & show what does userimage route do? (the controller function) & ill show u what to do

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja exactly , i want to change the user image . each user should show its image , based on that $pass_the_id . and i don't know how to send that .

Comment: show me the userimage route code & function

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja thank you so much , i will do that now .

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja it works in the add button , and it does its job . but in update . the problem is that i can't send the id for the route

Comment: okay that's clear, and the picture will be shown in #student-update modal right?

Comment: ` <img src="{{ route('userimage',['id' => $pass_the_id ])}}"/>` do you wanna show images like this? ))

Comment: @AlexandrBiship yes , is there any easier solution to this problem ? please help me if you can . i don't know what i should do about it .

Comment: @AlexandrBiship can you suggest me an easier solution?

Comment: when you get userinfo(`$.get("{{ URL::to('student/edit') }}",{id:id},function (data) {` , can you get a image url as well?

Comment: @AlexandrBiship No , and thats my problem .

Answer (score 0):

On Ajax Success call to pass data to view with return response() in laravel this is the simple way with an example -

js function

```
$(document).on('change', '[name="abc_field"]', getCitiesByState);

 function yourAjaxCall() {
    var data_to_pass = $(`[name='get_data_selector']`).val();
    var $selector    = $(`[name='selector']`);
    $.ajax({
        url: route('your_route'),
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            data: data_to_pass
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function success(data) {
            $selector.empty().append(data);
        },
    });
}
```

call to controller from ajax call

```
public function your_route_function()
{
    $result = Abc::where('column',request('data'))->get();

    return response()->json([
        'result' => view('viewfilename.fields._option', ['options' => $result])->render(),
    ]);
}
```

view path  "resources\viwes\viewfilename\fields_option.blade" to render

```
<option value="">{{ $defaultText or 'Select' }}</option>
@foreach($options as $value => $name)
    <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Hope this will help you to render view through ajax call.